# Adding FontCombo to ToolBar by using CMFCToolbarFontComboBox in VC++2012?

Tags: mfc

I'm using VC++2012 to learn MFC programming, with the wizard generation, there are systems toolbar already. I want to edit text in my document, so I set view class to derived from "CRichEditView" class then I can add button and control to toolbar, but a problem is that I cannot add any controls to toolbar which the toolbar itself has CMFCToolBar as a baseclass.I actually planned to add a font combobox and fonsize combobox, eventhough I did do a researh,but it's still no answer where is wrong.Here are some sample link I failed to compile.

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/adding-a-combo-box-to-a-toolbar/184416845
After modified I got it buid without failed, but I have no idea why popup "debug assertion failed" error.

some sample from here also didn't work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15084210/the-combobox-on-the-toolbar-can-load-itemsprint-them-in-the-output-window-while

Anyway I seem to found out here--->
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb982559.aspx
I think it is something I want to, but with my knowledge at the moment, after took a look at the Remarks, I really have no idea how to do each step in more detail.

I prefered to use a CMFCToolBarFontComboBox class with CMFCToolBar, and with CRichEditView.

Any answer or recommended would be appreciate.

Comment: Tell us were you get the ASSERT..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, now I have a Fontcombo in my toolbar, my next question is that how to change the selected font in CRichEditView when I'm changing a fontname in the list.

I have used CMFCToolbarFontComboBox::Setfont(), but didn't work, what handler should I deal with, or is there anyway(exclude: WordPad Sample) to sync font between font in view and font in list of combo?

Comment: All solved :1. get the MSOFFICE2007DEMO Sample for code reference   2.take a good looking at MSDN 3.google it 4.DONE in a week!

Answer (score 0):

You find a complete sample here.
[WordPad Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb984195%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
It is exactly what you are currently trying to build.

Comment: Error 1 error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated e:\vs2012 projects\samples\wordpad - copy\resource.h 206 1 WordPad

Comment: This is a error that happens, because there was a previous error. Please try to acquire information on your own, before you post again...

Comment: Warning 2 warning C4005: 'ID_OLE_VERB_POPUP' : macro redefinition e:\vs2012 projects\samples\wordpad - copy\resource.h 206 1 WordPad <--- when I loaded solution there is popup updated need, I think because it's VS2010, since I'm using 2012, it maybe a resource between version??

Comment: This is a change in VS-2012. This id is now pre defined. Just remove line 206 from resource.h. Should fix the compiler error.

Comment: It's passed without failed many thank to you,but on building process there are something like this -->  buttondi.cpp
1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>  cntritem.cpp
1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)
1>  colorlis.cpp
1>  _WIN32_WINNT not defined. Defaulting to _WIN32_WINNT_MAXVER (see WinSDKVer.h)...so on... <--- Can I fix this? However,eventually I can now take a time to study on this(WordPad) which I have got it long time ago, but never be able to see about how does it work.Thank you, xMRi!

Comment: This comment just tells you that the newest API is used to compile. If you want to restrict your program to work with XP or Vista you should set your own defines for _WIN32_WINNT and others...

Comment: Updated : It's not support with 24bits toolbar color, although there be a completed building, but it will some reasons ends up with an error at bartool.cpp(in debugging mode), I found this when trying to changed a bitmap in the resource file. In the same way, I can't use it to combined with my project by setting the project to MDI Document, VS2008's style view including some OLEs, all these will lead the toolbar class to be a "CMFCToolBar" rather than "CToolBar", so I think this should be a main problem here. I still want to learn about "CMFCToolbarFontComboBox".Do you know how2?-(reunchecked)

Comment: In addition to : For a problem when I'm trying to add it(WordPad's Formatbar part with all required code&files) to the new project in VC++2012, if I reduced a bitmap resource to be 4bits color, the next error will be instead at ---> VERIFY(GetOwner()->SendMessage(WM_NOTIFY, fh.idFrom, (LPARAM)&fh)); <---at line 113 in formatba.cpp. Anyone feels free to make a comment, just wants (a FontCombo and FontSize) two things to be placed on toolbar?